# Add Drop down box information

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to add drop down box information:

```
USERNAME EMAIL                  ROLE
```

3   user    user@mail.com   12345

How to add role so that it shows administrator or Manager? instead of the codes?

models/Mpages.php

```
public function add_user()
{   
    $options = [
      'roles' => 'administrator',
    ];

    $hash = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $hash,
        'role' => form_dropdown('roles', $options, 'administrator')     
    );      

    return $this->db->insert('login', $data);

}
```

controllers/Cpages.php

```
public function addusers() { 

    $data['successmessage'] = "";

    $data['options'] = array(
        'administrator' => 'Administrator',
        'manager'       => 'Manager',
    );

    $this->Mpages->add_user();

    $this->load->view('addusers', $data); 

}
```

Comment: What kind of result did you get?

Comment: Nevermind.  I finally found the answer.

Comment: If you find the answer, answer yourself and tell everybody how you have done it.

Comment: gives me good point for that lol.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer key:

controllers/Cpages.php

```
 public function addusers() { 

    $data['successmessage'] = "";

    $data['options'] = array(
        'administrator' => 'Administrator',
        'manager'       => 'Manager',
    );

    $this->Mpages->add_user();

    $this->load->view('addusers', $data); 

}
```

models/Mpages.php

```
public function add_user()
{   
    $options = [
      'roles' => 'administrator',
    ];

    $hash = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $hash,
        'role' => $this->input->post('roles')       
    );      

    return $this->db->insert('login', $data);

}
```